# Rails - adding ruby code to link_to tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

Is there anyway to put the ruby code inside the link_to tag, like this:

```
<%= link_to '<%= b.name %>', {id: b.id, action: 'db_seemore'}%>
```

I am asking because i wanted to make link_to button with the name of the record which is redirecting the user to the record's page.

All help is appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `<% %>` ruby code works. Just delete `''`

```
<%= link_to b.name, {id: b.id, action: 'db_seemore'}%>
```

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I mispelled the 'name'. Thanks for your time!